# remove html tags python bugs?

Tags: python, html

```
import time
with open('C:/Users/LQ/Downloads/test.txt',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
s = f.read()
start = end = 0
while start <= end:
    if s[start] == '<' and s[end] == '>':
        s.replace(s[start:end + 1],'')
        start = end + 1
        end = start
    elif s[start] == '<' and s[end] != '>':
        end += 1
    elif s[start] != '<':
        start += 1
        end = start
```

**the bug is string index out of range but I don't know how to fix it.**

Comment: Try printing start and end at each step, and using a very short input, e.g. `<a>`

Comment: ok. I will have a try. thx!